# API GET request returns 404

Tags: python, django, rest, get

I'm currently developing a Django web application which is supposed to add some functionality to online shops based on InSales (a popular Russian web platform). I use the official InSales lib for Python called `pyinsales` to get objects like **orders** and **products** from registered shops.

The InSales API is based on REST requests with XML. I use the code below to get information about orders in the Django shell:

```
from install.models import Shop
from insales import InSalesApi
shop = Shop.objects.get(shop_url='shop-url.myinsales.ru')
api = InSalesApi(shop.shop_url, 'trackpost', shop.password)
orders = api.get_orders()
```

Here `shop.shop_url` is the shop URL ("oh, really?"), trackpost is the name of my app and `shop.password` is the password needed to connect. Password is generated by MD5 (that's an InSales rule). And here I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/insales/api.py", line 32, in get_orders
    return self._get('/admin/orders.xml', {'per_page': per_page, 'page': page}) or []
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/insales/api.py", line 291, in _get
    return self._req('get', endpoint, qargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/insales/api.py", line 307, in _req
    response = getattr(self.connection, method)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/insales/connection.py", line 85, in get
    return self.request('GET', path, qargs=qargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/insales/connection.py", line 70, in request
    (method, path, resp.status, body), resp.status)
insales.connection.ApiError: GET request to /admin/orders.xml?page=1&per_page=25 returned: 404
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<errors>\n  <error></error>\n</errors>\n'
```

I've already checked everything for mistakes. Password is generated properly (according to official documentation), shop URL is correct and all the methods from the lib are used correctly. InSales tech support doesn't response, so now I have no idea about what is happening.

**I don't want you to debug this issue, but I'd like to know what can cause the 404 error** (except obvious things, like incorrect URL or password). Thanks everybody who tries to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analysing the pyinsales code on github, I realised that **url** should be a subdomain name on **myinsales** domain, so if the full url is **http://shop.myinsales.ru/** then the first argument in pyinsales should be **shop**. That's a pity no one working on the module pointed that in readme, but such things happen

Answer (score 0):

404 mean that the server couldn't find what you requested.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404

So it's not an authentication issue, it seems like there are no orders at that particular endpoint.

Have you tried using the python "requests" package instead of using the "pyinsales" module to request data from the endpoint directly? That way you can customize your own headers, etc.

You might also try testing the endpoints in a program like postman to ensure that the endpoints are valid before you try to hit them programmatically.

Comment: Well, that's too obvious (I bet everybody knows what is 404). What is funny - I have control of the shop. I am sure that there **are** objects there. Using `requests` is quite uncomfortable when there is an official module, so I didn't want to use it. But thanks anyway

Comment: Have you ensured that the endpoint itself works though? If you try to hit the endpoint using curl or a program like postman does it work?

Comment: Well, that's pretty hard to check because InSales is a very private and well... closed platform. But I am sure enough that the endpoint works because the site itself works and it works with lots of other apps that use the same API